# Consulta Select En MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

Buenas Tardes de ante mano un saludo y gracias por su tiempo estoy en una empresa con un sistema "semi abierto" por asi decirlo que solo me deja manipular el `select, from` mas no el `where` de mi las consultas esto trae como consecuencia una información que no necesitamos seria algo como un `articulo` con sus campos y uno de ellos es un campo `compuesto` este campo vale `1` o `2` si es `2` es un articulo compuesto todo seria muy facil si yo en mi consulta coloco un `where compuesto = 2` pero recuerden que no manejo eso y por ende me trae todo lo que integra ese producto , hablemos de una parrilla por ejemplo, pues me dice la sal, la salsa, la pimienta, todo lo relacionado a ese producto tendría esto alguna solución con una condicion `if` antes del `select`? esta es la consulta completa y recuerden el `where` no es colocado por mi sino por el código del sistema

```
select
  articulo.garantia,
  articulo.campo1,
  articulo.campo2,
  articulo.campo3,
  articulo.origen,
  articulo.referencia,
  operti.tipodoc,
  operti.codcliente,
  operti.nombrecli,
  operti.rif,
  operti.nit,
  operti.escredito,
  operti.estatusdoc,
  operti.vence,
  operti.orden,
  operti.estacion,
  operti.horadocum,
  operti.ampm,
  operti.factorcamb,
  operti.contacto,
  operti.documento,
  operti.emision,
  operti.totalfinal,
  operti.totbruto,
  operti.totdescuen,
  operti.totneto,
  operti.totimpuest,
  operti.totpagos,
  operti.factorcamb, 
  monedas.nombre   as nombremoneda,
  monedas.simbolo  as simbolomoneda,
  opermv.impu_mto,
  opermv.codhijo,  
  operti.vuelto,
  operti.dsctolinea,
  operti.dsctoend2,
  operti.dsctoend1,
  operti.notas as opertinotas,
  cliempre.direccion,
  cliempre.email,
  cliempre.telefonos,
  cliempre.numerofax,
  cliempre.perscont,
  opermv.codigo,
  opermv.nombre as nombre1,
  opermv.notas,
  opermv.unidad,
  opermv.timpueprc,
  opermv.preciofin,
  opermv.cantidad,
  opermv.montoneto,
  opermv.vendedor,
  opermv.preciounit,
  opermv.dsctounit,
  opermv.montototal,
  opermv.dsctoendm,
  opermv.tallas,
  opermv.colores,
  opermv.codhijo,
  opermv.agrupado,
  opermv.imp_nacional,
  opermv.imp_producc,
  operclit.tardebmto,
  operclit.tardebnom,
  operclit.tardebnum,
  operclit.mtotarjeta,
  operclit.bancotar,
  operclit.nrotarjeta,
  operclit.bcocheqmto,
  operclit.bcocheqnom,
  operclit.bcocheqnro,
  operclit.otrotipo,
  operclit.otroreferencia,
  operclit.efectivo,
  operclit.ncredito,
  operclit.monto,
  operti.sinimpuest,
  grupos.codigo,
  grupos.nombre,
  listvend.nombre
from 
  opermv
  left join operti on (opermv.agencia = operti.agencia)
                   and (opermv.tipodoc = operti.tipodoc)
                   and (opermv.documento = operti.documento)

  left join cliempre on (operti.codcliente = cliempre.codigo)

  left join listvend on (operti.vendedor = listvend.codigo)

  left join operclit on (operti.documento = operclit.documento and operclit.referencia=' ')
                    and (operti.tipodoc = operclit.tipodoc)

  left join grupos   on (opermv.grupo = grupos.codigo)

  left join articulo on (opermv.codigo = articulo.codigo)

  left  join monedas on (monedas.codigo     = if(operti.moneda='','000',operti.moneda))
   where opermv.id_empresa='HOTE21' and opermv.agencia='001' and opermv.tipodoc='FAC' and opermv.documento='*0000014' order by opermv.pid
```

Comment: Tu pregunta no es del todo clara. He entendido que tienes que ceñirte a como está la consulta escrita, ¿cierto?. Dada esa circunstancia, tendrás que filtrar los datos una vez obtenidos, desechando aquellos que no necesites. Por ejemplo, si recibes los resultados en un array, sacar de ese array aquellos datos que no necesitas, o crear un nuevo array solamente con los datos que necesitas.

Comment: no amigo, yo puedo jugar con el select, excepto añadir un where a mi consulta como dije todo seria simplie con un where compuesto = 2 para que solo me muestre los resultados que son de ese tipo pero no puedo agregar ningun where a mi consulta necesito todo ese select tal cual esta pero debo traer solo los tipo compuesto = 2 pero no decirlo en un where, habra alguna otra manera? una condicion un if algo?? muchas gracias @A.Cedano

Comment: Curioso impedimento el tuyo... **¿No puedes ni añadir un `WHERE`, ni modificar el actual?** Si es así, tendrás que traer todos los datos, guardarlos en un arreglo y luego sacar de ese arreglo sólo los datos cuya clave `compuesto` sea igual a `2`. O, si puedes, escribir una consulta nueva, en la que puedes usar `WHERE`y todo lo que necesites. ¿Eso tampoco puedes, escribir tu propia consulta?

Comment: ok, la cuestión es que la empresa usa un software semi cerrado por así llamarlo y esta compilado en foxpro no podemos abrir el código solo modificar los reportes y la BD esta en MySql por ende podemos manipular las consultas pero el where lo genera este software y no podemos manipularlo. entonces tengo para trabajar un reporte y una consulta el reporte esta listo pero desde el sql es que muestra los datos asi que necesito solventar la consulta en sql ni mas ni menos algo como if set condicion select * from art pero no se plasmarlo ni se si se pueda

Comment: No entiendo mucho esto que dices: ***necesito solventar la consulta en sql ni mas ni menos algo como if set condicion `select * from art`*** ¿te refieres  a agregar como un segunda parte a la consulta que ya tienes? ¿Cómo lo vas a hacer, si dices que el sistema es el que agrega los `WHERE`? ¿Qué `WHERE` agregará en ese caso? Es muy extraño tu caso...

Comment: muy extraño lo se... ok mi pregunta en si se basa en: puedo agregar una condición con un if antes de ejecutar el select? y si fuese posible como seria

Comment: ¿Una condición antes de ejecutar el `SELECT`? Sí claro, puedes agregar una condición en el código antes de ejecutar el `SELECT`. Pero si esa condición no se cumple, el `SELECT` no se ejecutaría. También puedes agregar `IF` dentro del mismo `SELECT`, pero eso te serviría para poco, ya que el `IF` ahí lo que haría sería mostrar un dato por otro, ya que lo filtra los datos en sí son los `WHERE`.

Comment: ok, pero intentemos si? la consulta como la necesito esta en la pregunta recuerda ese where lo genera el sistema 3ro y necesito validar el campo compuesto antes de el select con este if es posible?

Comment: ¿Puedes Agregar/Modificar/Manipular los JOINS?

Comment: si amigo, si puedo